# Regex to match PEP440 compliant version strings

Tags: python, regex, pep

[PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440) lays out what is the accepted format for version strings of Python packages.

These can be simple, like: `0.0.1`

Or complicated, like: `2016!1.0-alpha1.dev2`

What is a suitable regex which could be used for finding and validating such strings?

Comment: Where is your regex, and what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same question. This is the most thorough regex pattern I could find. PEP440 links to the codebase of the packaging library in it's references section.

```
pip install packaging
```

To access just the pattern string you can use the global

```
from packaging import version
version.VERSION_PATTERN
```

See: https://github.com/pypa/packaging/blob/21.3/packaging/version.py#L225-L254

```py
VERSION_PATTERN = r"""
    v?
    (?:
        (?:(?P<epoch>[0-9]+)!)?                           # epoch
        (?P<release>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)                  # release segment
        (?P<pre>                                          # pre-release
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<pre_l>(a|b|c|rc|alpha|beta|pre|preview))
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<pre_n>[0-9]+)?
        )?
        (?P<post>                                         # post release
            (?:-(?P<post_n1>[0-9]+))
            |
            (?:
                [-_\.]?
                (?P<post_l>post|rev|r)
                [-_\.]?
                (?P<post_n2>[0-9]+)?
            )
        )?
        (?P<dev>                                          # dev release
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<dev_l>dev)
            [-_\.]?
            (?P<dev_n>[0-9]+)?
        )?
    )
    (?:\+(?P<local>[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_\.][a-z0-9]+)*))?       # local version
"""
```

Of course this example is specific to Python's flavor of regex.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I needed.

Comment: you've included your _comments_ in a regular string, so I don't expect this to work as-is

Comment: While this may be comprehensive I cannot use it as branch matching pattern in Travis.

Comment: It can be used with ```_regex = re.compile(r"^\s*" + VERSION_PATTERN + r"\s*$",
    re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)```

Answer (score 11):

I think this should comply with PEP440:

```
^(\d+!)?(\d+)(\.\d+)+([\.\-\_])?((a(lpha)?|b(eta)?|c|r(c|ev)?|pre(view)?)\d*)?(\.?(post|dev)\d*)?$
```

#### Explained

Epoch, e.g. `2016!`:

```
(\d+!)?
```

Version parts (major, minor, patch, etc.):

```
(\d+)(\.\d+)+
```

Acceptable separators (`.`, `-` or `_`):

```
([\.\-\_])?
```

Possible pre-release flags (and their normalisations; as well as post release flags `r` or `rev`), may have one or more digits following:

```
((a(lpha)?|b(eta)?|c|r(c|ev)?|pre(view)?)\d*)?
```

Post-release flags, and one or more digits:

```
(\.?(post|dev)\d*)?
```

Comment: It was a difficult problem to solve, and could very well be useful to someone working with Python packaging. Does that not make it a decent question?

Comment: More to the point, if anyone has a better solution I'd really like to know.

Comment: first thing first..ask the entire question..your regex has much more information than you pointed out in the question..